# When exactly Signalr IUserIdProvider's method GetUserId called by the signalr framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

When does the GetUserId method get called by the SignalR framework when we have a custom IUserIdProvider as follows:

```
public class RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        return  request.QueryString["userId"];
    }
}
```

How and when does the ConnectionId to UserId mapping happen and how does the following method work:

```
 Clients.User("1").notify(notificationsJson);
```

Does the user have to be authenticated for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The user does not need to be authenticated for a custom IUserIdProvider to work.

However, if the user is authenticated, and you don't replace the default IUserIdProvider with your own in SignalR's DependencyResolver, the client's user id will be equal to its `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

There isn't a mapping between the client's connection id and user id exactly, but when a client connects using SignalR, it will internally establish subscriptions to receive messages sent to both its connection id and user id. IUserIdProvider.GetUserId is invoked when each SignalR connection is established, so SignalR can set up the subscription.